# Hello World in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried running a python script:

```
print "Hello, World!"
```

And I get this error:

```
  File "hello.py", line 1
    print "Hello, World!"
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is going on?

Comment: I suspect this will become the most-frequently-asked Python question for the next couple of years.

Comment: Please post the results of `python --version`

Comment: Just a thought: Python 3.0 should come with "Py3k warnings" on by default. Think of how many thousands of SO/newsgroup questions could be prevented by doing this.

Comment: Yes, something as simple as the warning on ubuntu linux - which pops up when you type a command whose executable isn't installed - telling you how to install it and what command to use.

Comment: First time I see somebody asking a question about how to implement "Hello World" in a language. Makes you wonder what that says about the language if that's causing people trouble already... (since it's usually given as the first code example in any introduction).

Comment: Why can't it be simple as that? - print "Ukinayo" - Makes the world perfectly round.

Comment: @GregHewgill viewed 53k times, you weren't too wrong.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

```
print("Hello, World!")
```

You are probably using Python 3.0, where `print` is [now a function](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) (hence the parenthesis) instead of a statement.

Comment: Thank you, this worked.  I don't know why this isn't more common knowledge, because I just copy-pasted from the first Google result for Python Hello World.

Comment: "requires parenthesis" is not really the adequate explanation as to the change from 2.x to 3 :)

Comment: @MiffTheFox: Python 2.x uses print as a statement. The relatively new Python 3 made print a function instead. The majority of Python programmers are still using 2.x because of its extensive library and framework support, so 3.0 isn't nearly as adopted as you'd expect for now.

Comment: @paulo, its the most succinct. If I had said, it is now a function, I would have to then explain what the difference between a statement and an expression is and how a function fits into the whole picture.

Comment: They should have a special error message for cases like this with a bit more explanation. With all the documentation out there for Python 2, this kind of incompatible syntax change is bound to frustrate the uninitiated a lot.

Comment: Well, this certainly seems like a step in the wrong direction!

Comment: @Andrew: in what sense is this a step in the wrong direction? Now that print is a function, it can be treated like all other functions (and can thus be passed around, etc.)

Answer (score 115):

Unfortunately the [xkcd comic](http://xkcd.com/353/) isn't completely up to date anymore.

[image: https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/python.png]

Since Python 3.0 you have to write:

```
print("Hello world!")
```

And someone still has to write that `antigravity` library :(

Comment: http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/antigravity.py?view=markup&pathrev=66902

Comment: Whoa... your xkcd reference even has the hovertext. Is that xkcd's doing or yours?

Comment: @inetknght: If you look at the markup behind the post you see how the hovertext is done.

Comment: @inetknght the `title` attribute in `<img>` tag has been used for that purpose.

Comment: @KNU : Markdown has no <img> tag. The formatting works differently.

Answer (score 16):

In python 3.x. you use

```
print("Hello, World")
```

In Python 2.x. you use

```
print "Hello, World!"
```

Comment: Using 3.x requires less enthusiasm?

Comment: `` @LShaver Yes.