# Syntax error on hello world with python

Tags: python

The Following hello world example is giving me an error, any help would be useful

```
print("Hello","World", sep="***")


File "basicio.py", line 9
    print("Hello","World", sep="***")
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print()` is for python 3.x, to make it work in python 2.x you need to import it first:

```
In [3]: from __future__ import print_function

In [4]: print("Hello","World", sep="***")
Hello***World
```

Answer (score 3):

You are running python 3 code in a python 2 interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

You are using Python2 and and writing Python3 syntax.

Just type `print "hello, world"`

Or use `python3` from your prompt.

Comment: how do I install the Python 3 interpreter then? Google isnt helping much :(

Comment: Which platform do you want to install it? You will find the downloads here: http://www.python.org/download/releases/3.3.0/

Comment: I installed Py 3.3 but still typing `python` on the command prompt returns 2.7.3 any idea why this is happening?

Comment: that works, but so should I compile my files using `python3 filename.py`?

Comment: There you go! Yes and congrats on your first python3 program.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is not valid for Python 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using Python 2? This is Python 3 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate things in python: statements and functions. In python 2, print is a statement. In python 3 onwards, they turned print into a function, and allowed it to take arguments such as '*sep*'. You are using python 2, therefore if you ***have*** to use this extra functionality, upgrade to python 3.

For more information on the change in print, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077347/hello-world-in-python) out.